# What is wrong with my IIF statement i keep receiving errors

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT description as FOOD,
price,
price_increase
iif( price_increase/price < .10 or price_increase is null, 'Less than 10% Increase', 
 iif(price_increase/price > .15 , 'Greater that 15% increase ', ' ' ) )
from l_foods
where (price_increase/price) < .10 or price_increase is null, or (price_increase/price)
> .15
order by description;
```

[image: ERROR MESSAGE]

I am having trouble trying to complete this statement. My iif statement keeps giving me errors

Comment: You are missing a comma at the end of the previous line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the missing comma on the preceding line and the extra comma in the `WHERE` clause.

I should note that you can also use `switch()`:

```
select description as FOOD, price, price_increase,
       switch(price_increase < 0.10 * price or price_increase is null,
              'Less than 10% Increase', 
              price_increase > 0.15 * price,
              'Greater that 15% increase '
             )
from l_foods
where price_increase < 0.10 * price or
      price_increase is null or
      price_increase > 0.15 * price
order by description;
```

Notes:

- I put a `0` before decimal points, so the decimal point is easier to read.
- I prefer multiplication to division, because there is very little danger of an error (I suppose there could be an overflow error, but that is much less likely than divide by zero).
- `switch()` is fine, because you don't need the default option.  The `where` clause filters those out.

Comment: Thank you sir i greatly appreciate the help you always give me @Gordon Linoff